# Processing files in folders in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to avoid to write a code which does by figuring out the script...

Basically, I have thousand of files in the folder...
Each file has the following format

```
primary_id
secondary_id,score,date
```

Example would be:

```
file1.txt
1
12,3,2003-12-29
13,2,2003-12-29

file2.txt
2
22,1,2004-01-20
```

What I want is..to process these and create the following output for each of the files:

```
output1.txt
12,1,3
13,1,2

output2.txt
22,2,1
```

and so on

How do i do this using bash,awk unix scripting tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    FNR==1  { k=$0; close(fname); fname="output"++nr".txt"; next }
    { print $1,k,$2 > fname }
' file1.txt file2.txt

$ cat output1.txt
12,1,3
13,1,2

$ cat output2.txt
22,2,1
```

If you can have empty input files then you MAY want a different solution (probably gawk with ARGIND and/or BEGINFILE/ENDFILE) but you'd need to tell us how you'd want those handled.

Comment: Even it has been accepted, my feeling is, use the primary_id in new output file name directly.

Comment: That's a possibility but it may not be unique across all input files and then what? We'd need the OP to provide some more representative input and/or tell us more about his requirements to know if anything has to change.

Answer (score 2):

Another awk:

```
awk  'NR==1{id=$1;next}{print $1,id,$2}'  FS=',' OFS=',' infile
```

Comment: for multiple files, change `NR` to `FNR`, so it can be changed to : `awk  'FNR==1{id=$1;next}{print $1,id,$2 > "output" id ".txt"}'  FS=',' OFS=',' file*.txt`